# Projeto com arquitetura MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Estou tendo algumas dúvidas em relação a arquitetura MVVM.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que tem as seguintes características:
- Main form com conteúdo dinâmico
- Main form gera algumas tabs de acordo com a configuração
- Cada tab gera alguns paineis de acordo com a configuração

Há uma singleton que tem uma variável que guarda uma variável de extrema importância.

Meu projeto não usa o conceito MVVM mas estou querendo implementá-lo, ou pelo menos, conhecê-lo melhor a ponto de saber como realizar, caso seja opção, num projeto como esse.

As alterações feitas em cada painel, são enviados através de evento para o tab responsável para assim ser feito o Save da configuração modificada (todos são independentes).
Alterações na configuração do tab são enviados ao main form que guarda os dados da configuração da tab em questão. 
Alterações no form são salvos por ele mesmo.

Meu código originalmente tem o seguinte aspecto:

```
    public double OpacityBackground
    {
        get { return btnBackground.Opacity; }
        set
        {
            btnBackground.Opacity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OpacityBackground");

            OnPanelChangeData?.Invoke(this, new OnPanelChangeArgs()
            {
                Value = btnBackground.Opacity.ToString(),
                Type = OnChangeType.Opacity
            });
        }
    }
```

(sim, estou mexendo diretamente no btnBackground quando poderia associar uma variável ao background, mas é caso de estudo).

Nele estou binding assim:

```
<Slider 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="5,5,5,5"
    Width="100" 
    Name="sliderOpacity" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="1" 
    TickFrequency="0.1" 
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
    Value="{Binding OpacityBackground,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

A função OnPanelChangeData avisa o tab responsável que algum dado foi alterado.
Em caso de implementação MVVM seria algo assim:

```
private double opacityBackground;
public double OpacityBackground
{
    get { return opacityBackground; }
    set
    {
        opacityBackground = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Ok, eu associo o datacontext com uma instância da classe acima mas como vou chamar o event relacionado a avisar o tab? 
Caso eu queira acessar diretamente o valor de backgroundOpacity, seria:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
this.DataContext = viewModel;


// outra parte do código, outra função
viewModel.backgroundOpacity ?
```

Estou com algumas dúvidas em relação pois meus forms precisam se comunicar o tempo todo, inclusive cliques no mainform devem ter efeito no music, a depender do que for feito. Estou achando que o MVVM não seria adequado para meu caso.

Obrigado!

Comment: Caso queira aprender na prática a utilizar MVVM com WPF, eu indicaria [essa playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M) com excelentes videos sobre o assunto.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa playlist, obrigado pela recomendação!